# Can't get Cyanogenmod onto internal root

Tags: cyanogenmod

So: I was following instructions on this page to install the latest Cyanogen Mod on my S3
http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S:_Full_Update_Guide

I've installed the Hardcore kernel and Clockwork Mod.  However the site then says to place the CyanogenMod update.zip file on the root of the internal memory.  However I can't seem to do this.  The phone now won't boot (it keeps looping round).  I can get into clockwork mod however.

Can anyone advise how I can get the zip file onto the root of the internal memory?  I don't really understand why the site suggests I do this after installing Clockwork Mod.  Surely it would be wiser to do this before hand?

Comment: If you can get into CWM Recovery you can use ADB, see Matthews response below. Read more about ADB here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Answer (score 1):

CWM shouldn't have put your phone into a loop.  In any case, you can use `adb push` from your PC to put the update.zip file onto your internal storage at `/sdcard`.  (ADB is include with the [Android SDK Tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html).)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions I see here.

---

In the root menu of CWM there is an option `mounts and storage`. If you go into that, there should be an option to enable `mount USB storage`. That way you could place the zip file onto your internal memory. You can continue following your guide.

---

CWM also has an option to install a zip from an external SDcard. You could pull the SDcard out of your device and put it in your PC somehow. Then load the CyanogenMod zip onto your SDcard and insert it back into the device. After that you should find the option in CWM to install from your external SDcard. `install zip from sdcard` → `choose zip from sdcard` (instead of `choose zip from internal sdcard`).